# How to find out to which branch a specific subversion revision belongs?

Tags: svn, version-control, branch

When you do an `svn log` on the trunk there may be gaps in the revisions numbers:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1094 | user | 2013-04-23 09:14:01 +0200 (Tue, 23 Apr 2013) | 2 lines

commit msg

------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1067 | user | 2012-01-16 14:29:17 +0100 (Mon, 16 Jan 2012) | 1 line

other commit msg
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thats because the other commits were made on branches. The question is how do I determine to which branch a given revision belongs to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Log for repository **root** include all history for any subtree of repo

`svn log -v -q URL-OF-REPO-ROOT/ -r NNN -l 1`

will show log for revision NNN (`-r` option), affected files (`-v` option) and only this single revision (`-l 1` option)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, a given commit doesn't necessarily have to all be in the same branch. To get a quick answer of what files(and their given paths) were changed in a given commit, you could something like

```
svn diff --summarize -c r123456
```